# Call to a member function on a non-object getting errors

Tags: php, laravel

I tried so many time but this code is not working. I don't know why. It is a image upload form. This code worked for another form but here it's getting an error: `Call to a member function isValid() on a non-object`

```
$file = array('dest_img' => Input::file('dest_img'));
// checking file is valid.
    if (Input::file('dest_img')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
        $extension = Input::file('dest_img')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        $fileName = $s.'.'.$extension; 
        $imgPath= $destinationPath.'/'.$fileName;
        //return $imgPath;
        // renameing image
        Input::file('dest_img')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
        // sending back with message
        //Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
        //return Redirect::to('tblaze_admin/bannerAdd');

         $data=array(
                    'dest_title'  =>$input['dest_title'],
                    'dest_desc'  =>$input['dest_desc'],
                    'dest_img' =>$imgPath,
            );
            //$result=Cms::where('cms_id',$cms_id)->update($data);

        $result=Destination::where('dest_id',$dest_id)->update($data);
        if($result >0)
        {
            \Session::flash('flash_message','Destination Updated Successfull!!');
        }
         else
         {
          \Session::flash('flash_error_message','Destination Updation Failed!!');
         }  
}
```

I'm stuck at this code; please give a solution

Comment: Best practice: `$inputFile = Input::file('dest_img'); if (! $inputFile instanceof InputFileClass) { throw new \Exception('No File object'); }`

Comment: Input::file('dest_img') doesn't exist.. try to use dd() on your request or the laravel's Log to track the issue down.. we dont have sufficient information in your code to provide you with solution!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag? Or if you're using the `Form` builder, `'files' => true`?

Answer (score 0):

`Input::file('dest_img')` is not an object. You might have not loaded the classes that define `Input`. Check that laravel is bootstrapped correctly.